# TypeError: this.classes is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Есть такой React-компонент

**saver.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const saverStyles = {
    btn: {
        padding: '2px'
    }
}

class SaverWidget extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const isSaved = !this.props.isEdited;

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.props.onSave} className={this.classes.btn} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Сохранить</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.props.onDiscard} className={this.classes.btn} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Отмена</Button>
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default withStyles(saverStyles)(SaverWidget)
```

(Кнопки "Сохранить" и "Отмена", которые сохраняют или отменяют изменения, сделанные пользователем, и которые включены только когда какие-то изменения были.)

Но если его использовать, например

**в другом файле:**

```
import SaverWidget from './path/to/saver.js'
...
    <SaverWidget onSave={один колбэк} onDiscard={другой колбэк} isEdited={true} />
```

То валится так:

> TypeError: this.classes is undefined

```
  16 | 
  17 | return (
  18 |     <div>
> 19 |         <Button onClick={this.props.onSave} className={this.classes.btn} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Сохранить</Button>
     | ^  20 |         <Button onClick={this.props.onDiscard} className={this.classes.btn} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Отмена</Button>
  21 |     </div>
  22 | )
```

Как исправить код?

Comment: `this.props.classes`

Comment: @Doigrales спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this.props.classes – Doigrales

Надо заменить **this.classes** на **this.props.classes**

Рабочий код:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const saverStyles = {
    btnDiv: {
        padding: '4px',
        display: 'inline-block'
    }
}

class SaverWidget extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const isSaved = !this.props.isEdited;
        const classes = this.props.classes;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={classes.btnDiv}>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onSave} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Сохранить</Button>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.btnDiv}>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onDiscard} className={classes.btn} variant="contained" size="medium" color="primary" disabled={isSaved}>Отмена</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default withStyles(saverStyles)(SaverWidget)
```